# Keyboard shortcuts for Chrome PDF Viewer

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, pdf-reader

I have found this help page: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1060734

But it only provides save and print keyboard shortcuts, I've to have shortcuts for the other functions (Fit Width, Zoom In/Out etc).

Do they exist?

Comment: The support link takes me to a "Adobe Flash isn't working" page.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here are the shortcuts you need:

- Zoom in: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>
- Zoom out: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
- Toggle between *Fit Width* and *Fit Page*: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>
- Rotate clockwise: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>
- Rotate counter-clockwise: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
- Download PDF: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>
- Print PDF: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Scroll one page up: <kbd>PgUp</kbd>
- Scroll one page down: <kbd>PgDn</kbd>
- Search Document: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: On my keyboard (a Nordic QWERTY), "+" and "\" are on the same key, so "Ctrl-+" and "Ctr-\" both zoom in

Comment: @jaam If I am not mistaken, on Nordic layout, instead of \, you must hit `AltGr`-`+`. So, in that case, I believe `AltGr`-`Ctrl`-`+` should do the Fit Width and Fit Page. Of course, the Nordic version of Chrome might have a different set of shortcut for those.

Comment: `Right` and `Left` change one page at a time for me. `PgUp` and `PgDn` scroll one screen at a time. It is the same if you are viewing one page at a time, but different if you are zoomed in.

Comment: On an ABNT2 (Brazilian Portuguese) keyboard, **Toggle between Fit Width and Fit Page** is `CTRL + }`.

Comment: Important addition: `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `G` allows you to jump to a page.

Comment: Another addition: Arrow Keys to scroll smoothly up and down

Answer (score 1):

I've tried some common hotkeys, you can zoom in with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> (either regular one or the one on numpad), zoom out with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, and return zoom to initial value with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>.

Comment: Yep standard "website zooming" will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

To **Fit Page** for the Chrome PDF Viewer on *Mac*:

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl ^</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Just '+' and '-' for me zooms a PDF without zooming the webpage/controls.